# Are graphical neural networks the right approach for isomorphic graphs?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, graph-theory, graph-neural-network

I have a set of $N$ observations ($N>100,000$):

- each observation takes the form of a homogeneous, undirected graph $G_n=(V,E)$
- all graphs $G_n$ have the same nodes and edges - around 5,000 nodes and 50,000 edges.
- edges have a weight property, which is the same in every graph in $N$
- each node is labelled with a binary value ($ v \in { {\{0,1\} } }$). Each observation has a different set of node labels.
- Each graph has a corresponding classification ($y$), which is a binary label.

**Essentially each graph is structurally the same (isomorphic), actually has the same labels, but has a different binary value.**

We are aiming to do three things:

1. Train a binary classifier to classify each graph
2. Identify which nodes in the graph are most important for this classification, ideally doing some sort of causal inference
3. Cluster graphs (that is, cluster similar graphs, not node clustering)

My reading has pointed towards using a graph neural networks (e.g. graph convolutional neural networks, graph attention networks) for these tasks, but these architectures are typically used in cases where graphs do not always take the same structure (eg graphs representing molecules in terms of atoms and bonds).

**Are graphical neural networks the right approach when working with graphs with an invariant structure?** If not, how can I encode this structural information in another deep learning architecture? We don't want to lose this structural information and just treat the nodes as a list, as we know there are high order interactions between nodes, which would not necessarily be learnt by a neural network unless it was very large and had a lot of training data.

Bonus: ideas on the best methods to tackle aims 2 and 3 (clustering and node importance). For clustering, options include a [(variational) autoencoder](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.07308.pdf%5D) type approach to embed graphs and then cluster their embedding, or adding a clustering loss to a GCN architecture.

Comment: great question, I am also thinking about this currently... What did you end up doing?